# how to calculate total loss using losses of batches

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I want to train a neural network and I want to check its total loss in every 100 epoch but I get the error `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate ...` in line #1, sometimes I get this error but this time because I've tried big numbers of neuron in hidden layers I think this time this error may be real, even though I tried

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
import gc
gc.collect()
```

which are codes recommended to fix the error I just mentioned so my question is not how to solve the error as I said this time it may be correct (not really even trying to know if the 3GB GPU capacity is full or not), and I just want to know is there any other way to calculate all train data loss? even with using the loss of batches.

I think another way of asking this question is how to calculate total loss using losses of batches?

btw any other suggestions about my hidden layer sizes are also appreciable because I can't really even overfit my 400000 samples train dataset.

````
input_size = 83
skipcolumns= 3
hidden_size = 640
output_size = 12
num_epochs = 10000
batch_size = 20000
learning_rate = .001
n_total_steps=int(len(trainx)/batch_size)+1
def seperator(i,divide,p):
    return int((p[1]-p[0])/divide*i+p[0]),int((p[1]-p[0])/divide*(i+1)+p[0])
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.lin = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.leakyrelu =nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=False)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.l4 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.l5 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.l6 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.lout = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        # out = self.relu(out)
        # out = torch.sigmoid(out)
        out = self.lin(x)
        out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        out = self.l2(out)
        out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        out = self.l3(out)
        out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        # out = self.l4(out)
        # out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        # out = self.l5(out)
        # out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        # out = self.l6(out)
        # out = self.leakyrelu(out)
        out = self.lout(out)
        
        # no activation and no softmax at the end
        return out

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
tti=time.time()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for btch in range(n_total_steps):
        stind,endind=seperator(btch,n_total_steps,[0,len(trainx)])
        thisx = trainx[stind:endind].to(device)
        thisy = trainy[stind:endind].to(device)
        outputs = model(thisx)
        loss = criterion(outputs , thisy)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        x=1/0
    if epoch%10==0:
        print(time.time()-tti)
        if epoch%100==0:
            thisx = trainx.to(device)
            thisy = trainy.to(device)
            outputs = model(thisx) #1
            loss = criterion(outputs , thisy)
            print(loss.item())
```
````